# spring boot tests and embedded elastic server

Tags: spring-boot

The documentation says that writing @SpringbootTest doesnt mean we load all the configuration

We should be able to test a slice of application at a time

I have a case where one module talks to elastic search and we spin up `EmbeddedElasticsearchServer`  in integration tests

However I have hard time figuring out how to define @Configuration classes, how to load them in test and how to make sure that elasticsearch server spins up once for all the tests

Comment: why not mocking elasticsearch class? and also check `EmbeddedElasticsearchServer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the @SpringBootTest. But you can use the below template for elasticsearch Integration est with embeddedserver

v7.0.0

```
@ESIntegTestCase.ClusterScope(scope = ESIntegTestCase.Scope.SUITE, numDataNodes = 1, numClientNodes = 0, transportClientRatio = 0, supportsDedicatedMasters = false)
@RunWith(com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class)
public class TestWatsonBulkIT extends ESIntegTestCase {
  @Override
protected boolean addMockHttpTransport() {
    return false;
}
    @Override
protected Settings nodeSettings(int nodeOrdinal) {
    Settings.Builder builder = Settings.builder()
            .put(super.nodeSettings(nodeOrdinal))
            .put(NetworkModule.TRANSPORT_TYPE_KEY, Netty4Plugin.NETTY_HTTP_TRANSPORT_NAME)
            .put(NetworkModule.HTTP_TYPE_KEY, Netty4Plugin.NETTY_HTTP_TRANSPORT_NAME)
            .put(HttpTransportSettings.SETTING_HTTP_PORT.getKey(), 9200)
            .put(HttpTransportSettings.SETTING_HTTP_HOST.getKey(),"127.0.0.1");
    Settings settings = builder.build();
    return settings;
}
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    beforeClass();
    super.setUp();
}
@Test
public void test_1(){ // your integration test code here }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We should be able to test a slice of application at a time

This is possible by providing classes in `@SpringBootTest` annotation. I usually go for this option in order to not load everything. Let's say,

Controller:
SampleController -> ConsumerService (autowired)

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ConsumerService.class, SampleController.class})
public class TestSample {

    @Autowired
    SampleController sam;

    @Test
    public void testSam() {
        sam.sample();
    }

}
```

I do have bunch of services but they won't be loaded and so their dependencies autowired.

If this is not what you're looking for please enhance your question by adding some sample codes.